# Update specific row layout from ListView, custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, button, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I'd like to update a specific row when I click on the Accept button that belongs to that row, but somehow it's updating the wrong row, I'd like to get some guidance on how to solve this.

I press Accept on the first row, but the second one got updated instead.

Here's my code:

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

    private View listRow;
    private String mOrderId;
    private LinearLayout userNotChosenLayout, userChosenLayout;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> users, String orderId) {
        super(context, 0, users);
        mOrderId = orderId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        listRow = convertView;

        if (listRow == null) {
            listRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_my_order_users, parent, false);
        }
        User currentUser = getItem(position);
        TextView userName = (TextView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.textview_user_name);
        userName.setText(currentUser.getName());
        setListeners(position);
        return listRow;
    }

    private void setListeners(final int position) {
        Button acceptBtn = (Button) listRow.findViewById(R.id.button_accept_user);
        acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "UserID: " + getItem(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new AcceptUser().execute(mOrderId, getItem(position).getId());

                View view = getView(position, listRow, null);

                userChosenLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.user_chosen_layout);
                userNotChosenLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.user_not_chosen_layout);

                userChosenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                userNotChosenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You should never call `getView()` directly. It is supposed to be used only from the system.

Answer (score 1):

if it always updates row below then it is supposed to - then just remove 1 from position.

Tho, ListView is deprecated, just use RecyclerView, it is way lighter and easyer to use (if you still going to be having problems - then post it then)

RecyclerView sample by google: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Searchable and expandable recycerview samples(within dialog container, tho idea is the same): https://github.com/WithoutCaps/DialogsCheatSheet